# Wont delete a document in mongodb (using moongoose) when a user leaves a discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Wont delete a document in mongodb (using moongoose) when a user leaves a discord server.

So i made this code where when a user joins i get his info and save it to a new document in mongodb.when he leaves the discord server i want to delete that user who left his info document but i cannot do it for somereason here is my code:
member join:

````
const test = require('../schmeas/GuildSchema.js');

module.exports = {
  name: Events.GuildMemberAdd,
  once: false,
  async execute(member) {
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('1111700932858761278');
    const welcomeMessage = `Welcome, ${member}! Enjoy your time here.`;

    welcomeChannel.send(welcomeMessage);

    try {
   let forn = new test({   
        User:  member.user.username,
        Guild: member.guild.id,
        id: member.id });
        await forn.save()
        .then(s => console.log(`saved : ${s}`))
          .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error saving document:', error);
  });


     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving new member data:', error);
    }
  },
};```


member leave.js:
```const { Events } = require('discord.js');
const test = require('../schmeas/GuildSchema.js');

module.exports = {
  name: Events.GuildMemberRemove,
  once: false,
  async execute(member) {
    let channelwel = await member.guild.channels.cache.get('1111700932858761278');
    let thing = `User ${member.user.tag} left. Bye!`;

    try {
      const data = await test.findOne({
        User: member.user.id,
        Guild: member.guild.id,
        id: member.user.id
      }) 
      console.log(data)

     
        const deleted = await test.deleteOne({
            User: member.user.id,
            Guild: member.guild.id,
            id: member.user.id
          })
          .then(s => console.log(`delete ${s}`))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
           console.log(deleted.deletedCount)    
      
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred during deletion:', error);
    }

    channelwel.send(thing);
  },
};``` 

any help will be appreciated
````

Comment: Well what behavior _is_ it doing? Are you getting an error, what logging statements get printed, etc

Comment: i updated ny code and put console.log(data) and i get null
delete [object Object]
Error occurred during deletion: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deletedCount')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\16478\Downloads\discord.bot\events\no.js:27:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: i just updated my code again

Comment: `console.log` returns nothing, but you then assign this nothing to `deleted` variable

Comment: so what should i do im confused?

Comment: Remove .then(s => console.log(`delete ${s}`))

Comment: it didnt delete the document @Konrad

Comment: nvm i fixed it i made  a typo